# Using "seed" based math to recreate application instances

Tags: string, algorithm, math, hash, seed

Okay so I was thinking today about *Minecraft* a game which so many of you are so familiar with, I'm sure and while my question isn't directly related to the game I find it much simply to describe my question using the game as an example.

My question is, is there any way a type of "seed" or string of characters can be used to recreate an instance of a program (not in the literal programming sense) by storing a code which when re-entered into this program as a string at run-time, could recreate the data it once held again, in fields, text boxes, canvases, for example, exactly as it was.

As I understand it, Minecraft takes the string of ASCII characters you enter, all which truly are numbers, and performs a series of operations on it which evaluate to some type of hash or number which is finite... this number (again as I understand) is the representation of that string you entered. So it makes sense that because a string when parsed by this algorithm will always evaluate to the same hash. 1 + 1 will always = 2 so a seeds value must always equal that seeds value in the end. And in doing so you have the ability to replicate exactly, worlds, by entering this sort of key which is evaluated the same on every machine.

Now, if we can exactly replicate worlds like this this is it possible to bring it into a more abstract concept like the following?...

Say you have an application, like Microsoft Word. Word saved the data you have entered as a file on your hard drive it holds formatting data, the strings you've entered, the format of the file... all that on a physical file... Now imagine if when you entered your essay into Word instead of saving it and bringing your laptop to school you instead click on *parse* and instead of creating a file, you are given a hash code... Now you goto school you know you have to print it. so you log onto the computer and open Word... Now instead of open there is an option now called *evaluate* you click it and enter the hash your other computer formulated and it creates the exact essay you have written.

Is this possible, and if so are there obvious implementations of this i simply am not thinking of or are just so seemingly part of everyday I don't think recognize it? And finally... if possible, what methods and algorithms would go into such a thing?

**[EDIT]**

I had to do some research on the anatomy of a seed and I think this explains it well

> The limit is 32 characters or for a
>   numeric seed, 19 digits plus the minus sign.
>
> Numeric seeds can range from -9223372036854775808 to
>   9223372036854775807 which is a total of 18446744073709551616  Text
>   strings entered will be "hashed" to one of the numeric seeds in the
>   above range. The "Seed for the World Generator" window only allows 32
>   characters to be entered and will not show or use any more than that."

BUT looking back on it lossless compression IS EXACTLY what I was
describing after re-reading the wiki page and remembering that (you
are very correct) the seed only partakes in the generation, the final
data is stores as a "physical" file on the HDD (which again, you are correct) is raw uncompressed data in a file

So in retrospect, I believe I was describing lossless compression, trying in my mind to figure out how the seed was able to replicate the exact same world, forgetting the seed was only responsible for generating the code, not the saving or compression of it.

So thank you for your help guys! It's really appreciated I believe we can call this one solved!

Comment: You're describing [lossless compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression)

Comment: @user3386109 I've read this and it appears as though this is very, very similar to what I was thinking of... so in the case of minecraft... how does a seed play into the lossless compression? and also... what file types are generally the result of a lossless compression (forgive me I'm simply trying to determine which files in minecraft itself are responsible for this seamless duplication and how i myself can replicate the methods used. I've been programming in Java for quite some time and have recently worked my way into C.

Comment: We need to clarify some things with regards to minecraft. First, how long is the string of ASCII characters? Second, are you saying that you can start a game of minecraft play for 3 hours smashing and building, and then get a short ASCII string that contains the game state, OR are you saying that the ASCII string just makes the same starting map on all computers?

Comment: What minecraft does to create the world from a short seed is [procedural generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation). What you are talking about is some kind of remarkably good compression. You might want to read aboout **kolmogorov/solomonoff complexity** for the theoretical limits here, or **perfect hashing** for the background to producing as-short-as-possible hashes from known datasets.

Comment: @AakashM this is close to what I was going for and may actually be of use to me in the future when i work with procedural generation and compression, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities to achieve this "string" that recovers your data. However they're not all applicable depending on the context.

1. An *actual seed*, which initializes for example a [peudo-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), then allows to recreate the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28056965/1387346)).

   This is possibly similar to what Minecraft relies on, because the whole process of how to create a world based on some choices (possibly pseudo-random choices) is known in advance. Even if we pretend that we have random numbers, computers are actually deterministic, which makes this possible.

   If your document were generated randomly then this would be applicable: with the same seed, the same [gibberish comes out](http://randomtextgenerator.com/).
2. Some key-value dictionary, or hash map. Then the values have to be accessible by both sides and the string is the key that allows to retrieve the value.

   Think for example of storing your word file on an online server, then your key is the URL linking to your file.
3. Compressing all the information that is in your data into the string. This is much harder, and there are strong limits due to [the entropy of the data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29). See [Shannon's source coding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem) for example.

   You would be better off (as in, it would be easier) to just compress your file with a usual algorithm (zip or 7z or something else), rather than reimplementing it yourself, especially as soon as your document starts having fancy things (different styles, tables, pictures, unusual characters...)

   With the simple hypothesis of 27 possible characters (26 letters and the space), Shannon himself shows in *Prediction and Entropy of Printed English* (Bell System Technical Journal, 30: 1. January 1951 pp 50-64, [online version](https://archive.org/details/bstj30-1-50)) that there is about 2.14 bits of entropy per letter in English. That's about 550 characters encoded with your 32 character string.

   While this is significantly better than the 8 bits we use for each ASCII character, it also shows it is very likely to be **impossible to encode a document in English in less than a fourth of its size**. Then you'd still have to add punctuation, and all the rest of the fuss.

Comment: This is the exact response I was hoping for! Thank you so much. I'll be doing research on all these topics soon. I appreciate your sharing of knowledge. Solved. And by far the best answer. Kudos.